# PXE Boot Arch Field DHCP Option 93

Tags: boot, dhcp, uefi, ipxe, bootp

The PXE Specification (http://www.pix.net/software/pxeboot/archive/pxespec.pdf) specifies the following values for the client system architecture of the DHCP

```
0 = IA x86 PC(2)
1 = NEC/PC98(2)
2 = IA64 PC.(2)
3 = DEC Alpha (2)
4 = ArcX86 (2)
5 = Intel Lean Client (2)
```

While the list looks a bit dated, what do modern Architectures use for the Arch Field.

e.g. If I have a ARM Server or a RISC-V server and want to perform a PXE Boot what value should I provide for the ARCH Field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5970#section-6:
"The following options have been assigned by the IANA from the option
number space defined in Section 24 of the DHCPv6 RFC [RFC3315]."

So, I would suggest that
https://www.iana.org/assignments/dhcpv6-parameters/dhcpv6-parameters.xhtml#processor-architecture is probably a good source.

Yes, this is DHCPv6, not DHCPv4, but no one appears to have cared enough to supersede [rfc4578](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4578) with an updated version.

Having reached that conclusion, I peeked in [UEFI 2.8](https://uefi.org/sites/default/files/resources/UEFI_Spec_2_8_final.pdf). In *Table 210. PXE Tag Definitions for EFI*, the description for `Client System Architecture` is:

> Type (2) Type is a two byte, network order, field that identifies the
> processor and programming environment of the client system. For the
> various architecture type encodings, see the table "Processor
> Architecture Types" at “Links to UEFI-Related Documents” (http://uefi.org/uefi)
> under the heading “Processor Architecture Types

That link in fact points to [the IANA page](https://www.ietf.org/assignments/dhcpv6-parameters/dhcpv6-parameters.xml#processor-architecture) again.

Comment: This is correct, there have been some missmatch in the past, but not related to ARM/RISC https://github.com/ipxe/ipxe/commit/af9afd0a86aeac1eed28b5028c3de669515fc7fc